# Pandas DataFrame - summing rows by multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, sum, multiple-columns

I am working on a Pandas dataframe in Python, i would like to do following rearrangement of the dataset :

[image: img]

I tried using for loops, but I wonder if there is any simpler solution using Pandas - i couldn't find anything more elegant.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year','Sex']).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
df.groupby(['Year','Sex'],as_index=False).sum()
```